# Remote Run over Git-Svn

Tags: teamcity, git-svn

I am trying to get `git-svn` working with the `teamcity` remote run.
Anyone had success witht that ?

The main querstion here is whether that is actually possible.

Comment: What do you use normally to start a remote run? What IDE?

Comment: I'm also interested in this. I use eclipse juno.

Answer (score 1):

Very late for an answer but nevertheless...

It's possible through remote run via commandline:
https://github.com/tendant/teamcity-git-svn

Script needs some updates to run on windows and I'll make a pull request to the author once I'm done fixing it.